# pagination in datatables with row grouping for groups

Tags: jquery, datatables

In datatables after row grouping pagination is applied for the total rows.But i want the pagination for the groups.Can anyone help on this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true
        }).rowGrouping({
            bExpandableGrouping: true,
            bExpandSingleGroup: false,
            iExpandGroupOffset: -1,
            asExpandedGroups: [""]
        });

        GridRowCount();
    });

    function GridRowCount() {
        $('span.rowCount-grid').remove();
        $('input.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').remove();

        $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('[id|=group-id]').each(function () {
            var rowCount = $(this).nextUntil('[id|=group-id]').length;
            $(this).find('td').append($('<span />', { 'class': 'rowCount-grid' }).append($('<b />', { 'text': rowCount })));
        });

        $('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter').append($('<input />', { 'type': 'button', 'class': 'expandedOrCollapsedGroup collapsed', 'value': 'Expanded All Group' }));

        $('.expandedOrCollapsedGroup').live('click', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
                $(this).addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').val('Collapse All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.collapsed-group').trigger('click');
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').val('Expanded All Group').parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.expanded-group').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mcsekar/RgKPZ/856/

In this fiddle the pagination is applied for the rows and not on the group.

Comment: So if you have 100 rows and 10 groups and you have "3" as the page size you want to show all rows for the first three groups?  Please clarify specifically your intent

Comment: `.live` is deprecated use `.on` instead

Comment: yes.the intend is as you mentioned @MarkSchultheiss